# JPQL join, diference between selects

Tags: join, jpql

I have 3 Table A, B, C related with Many-To-One

is there difference between these two?

```
"SELECT a FROM A a "
    + "INNER JOIN a.b b "
    + "INNER JOIN b.c "

"SELECT c.b.a FROM C c "
```

I have tested both, and both work how I want. However, is there any real difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query is invalid in the associations really are ManyToMany.

If they are ManyToOne or OneToOne, then the two queries are valid and equivalent.

Comment: but if there are no diference, when will I use first or second?

Comment: You'll use the first one if you need to add restrictions on b or c.